# How does `clangd` know where a function definition is when only one file has been indexed?

Tags: clang, llvm, language-server-protocol, clangd

How does `clangd` know where a function definition is when only one file has been indexed through the LSP (Language Server Protocol) message `textDocument/didOpen`?

This question is based off of the assumption that there is no `compile_commands.json` file for `clangd` to work with.

To the best of my knowledge `clangd` will *partially index*(?) a given file when `clangd` receives the LSP message `textDocument/didOpen` with no `compile_commands.json` file in the workspace(?).

Thus the index of the file being *partially indexed* will only reside in memory.

So how is `clangd` aware of definitions outside of the *partially indexed* file when it has no awareness of any outside files?

Or is it aware?

Or is it made aware of other files by some heuristic that looks at the relative path or the includes (`#include "<filename.hpp>"`) that only reside in directories `root-project-dir/src` and the likes thereof?

Comment: Since that's not well documented, the best way might be to debug into the source code.

Comment: I had [arguments](http://codinggorilla.com/?p=2377) about this whole thing with both LSP and Clangd folk. Clangd opens files from disk even though it does not receive a DidOpen call specifically for the include files. It does so in order to compile the source code, which would be impossible without the header files. So, yes, it's aware of far more than the DidOpen. That said, I'm not sure how it figures out the workspace and how it figures out the include paths. It's either asked for via message to client or something figures it out on the client side and then sends that to server.